# Stack Exchange offline question writing tool

Tags: linux, desktop-client, stack-exchange

I often use the Stack Overflow "Ask Question" site as a [rubber ducking tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), that is I have to explain my problem by typing it consistently and carry all relevant information into one place etc. It has the advantage over a plain text editor that if the rubber ducking did not help I have already a nicely formated question with all the relevant details that I can post on the respective SE site. Also the code highlighting etc. makes it easier to read what I wrote.

Now, I spend too much time on the SE network anyway so I'd like to have a way to take this ability out of my browser to be used when I intentionally cut my Internet connection to be better focused (I use the Leechblock Extension for this).

So I want to have a tool that:

- Runs on my desktop (Offline Capable WebApps are okay)
- Runs on my Linux (a MATE on Debian actually, but other flavors welcome).
- Supports the Stack Overflow markdown.
- Produces a preview.
- Does not need an Internet connection.

Nice to have:

- Display **read only** relevant question from Stack Overflow (other SE sites would be nice, but not so important).

Comment: Why don't you just click on _Ask Question_ and turn off your internet connection?

Comment: @nwp Because then it is already too late. I am seeing "Hot Meta Posts" and want to read them. Also, all the new questions on the Main page etc. No, when I land on stackoverflow I am kinda lost.

Comment: Use a customizable popup blocker maybe together with a different browser and block distracting stuff, take a self control course or try your luck on [stackapps](http://stackapps.com/).

Comment: Why not use a pen and paper like everyone else...? o.O

Comment: One of the biggest values to writing a question is seeing what related questions there are. More often than not, I find the answer to my question without ever asking it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Pen and Paper have really bad code highlighting. Also I miss copy/paste. And I can type like ten times faster than I write with my hands. Oh, and then there are Stack Traces, config elements etc. that I don't want to write down. Came to think of it, I know no one personally who uses pen and paper for this.

Comment: @corsiKa Yes. But to me one of the greatest risks in this is that I get lost in related questions to quickly. nwp made a splendid suggestion with the self control course but until then I have to use something different :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/editor) - it is exactly what you are asking for -

- The same editor as SO
- Works offline once loaded
- Free
- Works in browser so cross platform
- Can backup to Google Docs, etc.
- Syntax Highlighting available.

[image: Scrrenshot]

Comment: Looks great! I will test it throughly but this looks like what I had in Mind. Will see if it is actually "offline" capable. I wouldn't have expected something like this to live in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem myself. I needed a program that allowed me to write Markdown-based email templates with a live preview. I couldn't find anything online, so I wrote my own software to do this.

There's actually a .NET library called [MarkdownSharp](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) that is really useful for this. This takes a Markdown-formatted input and produces an HTML-formatted output.

From this, I created a hasty program I call TemplateOne. It is open-source with no license, I consider this to be Public Domain. I built this for Windows, but the entire project is compatible with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), so that you or someone else can build it for Linux. Apologies that this isn't a perfect one-click solution for you.

- [Download link (Windows)](http://www.mediafire.com/download/aobait7i6cztafe/TemplateOne(2).zip)
- [Source Code](https://github.com/thebluefish/TemplateOne)

Comment: I'll give it a look.